# Accept EULA error when running Python script in SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, sql-server-ml-services

I'm getting the error shown below when running Python script from SQL Server. I already installed ML services and reconfigured parameter `external scripts enabled`  to 1.

This is a SQL Server Developer edition installed on Windows 10.

> Msg 39111, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_execute_external_script, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 28]
>   The SQL Server Machine Learning Services End-User License Agreement (EULA) has not been accepted.

How can I accept it? Can't find any information. I've found only accepting EULA on docker containers, but it's not the same within this situation.

Comment: Is this SQL Server in Docker? Do you have `ACCEPT_EULA_ML=Y` in your startup environment variables? REF: https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/tree/master/linux/preview/examples/mssql-mlservices

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's not docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can face with this kind of error if we haven't restarted services after installing ML services.

Actually I've clicked on restart after installation in Configuration Manager several times, but I think due to local account permission it didn't restarted and didn't gave me any error messages. After restart with administrative account error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, was solved with a system restart.